# How to group by in spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have below data smaple data but in real life this dataset is huge.

```
A B 1-1-2018  10
A B 2-1-2018  20
C D 1-1-2018  15
C D 2-1-2018  25
```

I need to group by above data using date and generate key pair values

```
1-1-2018->key
-----------------
A B 1-1-2018  10 
C D 1-1-2018  15 

2-1-2018->key
-----------------
A B 2-1-2018  20
C D 2-1-2018  25
```

Can anyone please tell me how can we do that in spark in best optimize way (using java if possible )

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

Not Java but looking at your code above it seems you wants recursively set your dataframes into sub-groups by Key. The best way I know how to do it is by a while loop and its not the easiest on the planet earth.

```
//You will also need to import all DataFrame and Array data types in Scala, don't know if you need to do it for Java for the below code.

//Inputting your DF, with columns as Value_1, Value_2, Key, Output_Amount
val inputDF = //DF From above

//Need to get an empty DF, I just like doing it this way
val testDF = spark.sql("select 'foo' as bar")

var arrayOfDataFrames = Array[DataFrame] = Array(testDF)

val arrayOfKeys = inputDF.selectExpr("Key").distinct.rdd.map(x=>x.mkString).collect

var keyIterator = 1

//Need to overwrite the foo bar first DF
arrayOfDataFrames = Array(inputDF.where($""===arrayOfKeys(keyIterator - 1)))
keyIterator = keyIterator + 1

//loop through find the key and place it into the DataFrames array
while(keyIterator <= arrayOfKeys.length) {
  arrayOfDataFrames = arrayOfDataFrames ++ Array(inputDF.where($"Key"===arrayOfKeys(keyIterator - 1)))
  keyIterator = keyIterator + 1
}
```

At the end of the command you will have two array of same length DataFrames and Keys that match. Meaning if you select the 3rd element of the Keys it matches the 3rd element of the DataFrames.

Since this isn't Java and doesn't directly answer your question, does this at least help push you in a direction that might help (I built it in Spark Scala).

Comment: I would like to process input in parallel becuase input file is big, this while loop may make it sequential processing .